# FutureBuilder e setState no flutter

Tags: flutter

Muito bom dia a todos. Estou com um terrível problema no Flutter.
Estou usando a última versão,  3.7.7.
Vou descrever o problema:
Primeiro estou pegando da api as cidades e estados cadastrados.
Daí o user precisa selecionar um estado pra aparecer as cidades.
O problema que estou conseguindo receber os dados da api, o dropdown está funcionando mas ao chamar o onchange do dropdown que está fazendo um setState para o estado selecionado, acaba dando um reset na tela e volta a fazer o futurebuilder.

```
class EscolherVizinhancaPage extends StatefulWidget {
  static const routeName = '/escolher_vizinhanca';
  const EscolherVizinhancaPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<EscolherVizinhancaPage> createState() => _EscolherVizinhancaPageState();
}

class _EscolherVizinhancaPageState extends State<EscolherVizinhancaPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Map args = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as Map;

    UserModel user = args['user'];

    // variáveis para o estado
    String estadoSelecionado = 'Selecione o Estado';

    void verificarRetornoGetCidades(response) {
      if (response.statusCode != 200) {
        Alerts()
            .msg(context, 'Ops! Ocorreu um erro. Por favor tente novamente');
        return;
      }
    }

    Future getCidades() async {
      // esperar 2 segundos
      await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1));

      Uri url = Api().apiUrlLocal('getCidades');
      String apiKey = Api().apiKeyLocal();
      var response = await http.post(
        url,
        body: {
          'key': apiKey,
        },
      );

      verificarRetornoGetCidades(response);

      return response;
    }

    // widgets para o estado

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Selecionar Vizinhança'),
      ),
      body: SizedBox(
        width: double.infinity,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            FutureBuilder(
              future: getCidades(),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                  return const Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  );
                } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                  return const Center(
                    child: Text('Erro ao carregar'),
                  );
                } else {
                  Map retorno =
                      jsonDecode(utf8.decode(snapshot.data.bodyBytes)) as Map;
                  return DropdownButton(
                    items: ['Selecione o Estado', ...retorno['ufs']]
                        .map((e) => DropdownMenuItem(
                              child: Text(e),
                              value: e,
                            ))
                        .toList(),
                    onChanged: (value) {
                      print(value.toString());
                      // setState(() {
                      //   estadoSelecionado = value.toString();
                      // });
                    },
                    value: estadoSelecionado,
                  );
                }
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parece que existe uma falha na compreensão de dois pontos relacionados entre si. Vamos um de cada vez:

- Primeiro: O future utilizado pelo `FutureBuilder` deve ser armazenado fora dele.

Segundo a [documentação](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) da classe `FutureBuilder`:

> The future must have been obtained earlier, [...].
> It must not be created during the State.build [...]. If the future is created at the same time as the FutureBuilder, then every time the FutureBuilder's parent is rebuilt, the asynchronous task will be restarted.

Traduzindo livremente, isso significa que você não deve *criar* a conexão dentro do `FutureBuilder`. Você fez isso na linha `future: getCidades(),`. Quando você faz isso, sempre que essa parte da tela for re-desenhada, a função será chamada de novo e a conexão será resetada.

Existem muitos jeitos de resolver esse problema, mas o mais simples é:

1. Iniciar essa conexão no `initState`.
2. Armazenar seu resultado em uma variável da classe de estado.
3. No `futureBuilder`, use a variável que você armazenou.

No seu exemplo, ficaria assim:

```dart
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    conexao = getCidades(); // Passo 1: Chame a função dentro do initState e armazene em uma variável.
  }

late Future<Response> conexao; // Passo 2: A variável criada.

[...]

body: FutureBuilder<Response>(
    future: conexao, // Passo 3: Usar no FutureBuilder o future armazenado.
```

- Segundo: O método `build` é chamado sempre que a tela precisar ser redesenhada, e por alguns [outros motivos](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/build.html). Isso significa que: 1) Ele precisa ser o mais simples possível e 2) variáveis declaradas dentro dele serão re-declaradas sempre que o método for chamado novamente.

Note que você declarou as suas funções e variáveis todos dentro do método `build()`. Isso não é boa prática, como visto na documentação linkada acima. Esse método pode ser potencialmente chamado a cada frame (i.e. 60 vezes por segundo). Declarar uma função que é sempre a mesma acaba representando um risco de performance.

Para melhorar isso, **e** para utilizar a solução que sugeri aqui, repare que é necessário mover as funções locais de dentro do método build para fora, isto é, para se tornarem métodos da classe de estado. Também é necessário mover as variáveis de estado para a classe de estado (não é a toa que é esse o nome). Se não elas vão ser sempre redefinidas quando a tela for re-desenhada e no fundo não vão representar estado nenhum. Uma parte dessa solução você já viu no exemplo acima, mas segue um exemplo mais genérico deste ponto:

```dart
class _EscolherVizinhancaPageState extends State<EscolherVizinhancaPage> {
// Classe de estado. Os métodos e as variáveis devem ficar neste nível.


@override // Método que é chamado quando o estado é inicializado.
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    conexao = getCidades();
[...] // Outras inicializações necessárias.
  }

late Future<Response> conexao; // Variável sugerida acima, e as demais necessárias.
String estadoSelecionado = 'Selecione o Estado';
[...]


Widget build(BuildContext context) { // Método build que só descreve como a tela é desenhada e nada mais.
[...]
}
}
```

Com essas alterações o seu código deve trazer o resultado desejado.

Comment: tá e como eu pego os valores da rota, pois preciso do context para pegar os argumentos.